# Getting the URL of a Mailchimp list via the API

Tags: mailchimp

I'd like to link directly to a Mailchimp list in the Mailchimp dashboard. I have full API access, and the list id is: **bb7b537cd0**.

However, I notice when looking at the dashboard URL that the URL is:

https://us5.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/members/?id=212269

The id `212269` is **not** present in the API response data about this list.

Is there any way of linking directly to the list that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible through v3.0, but is possible in older versions. The main reason it was removed from 3.0 is that the dashboard URLs can change without notice, so relying on a particular algorithm to build them isn't advisable.